# How to make your parent clickable but children not?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I have `LinearLayout` which has 2 children which are used only as a preview. `LinearLayout` functionality here is same as `Button`. I want to disable any interaction with its children but make `LinearLayout`clickable by using `onClickListener`. Currently if I click on `Spinner` it will not trigger `onClickListener` of `LinearLayout`. I also called `spinner.isEnabled = false` in code.

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/clickableLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
    </Spinner>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:maxLength="9"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: disable all view except parent layout

Comment: I did that in XML and in code

Comment: what you want is whenever i click inside linearlayout, it should trigger the linarlayout clicklistner either it is textview or spinner ?

Comment: Yes, exactly this behavour

Comment: You cant do this.. just beacuse spinner and TextView is on LinearLayout so your click will be applied on these two.. and Spinner doesnot support onClick..so when you click on spinner it will not do anything and on clicking on TextView your onClick will be called..coz it supports onClick

Comment: you still need an answer???

Comment: Yes, I actually removed Spinner and added Spinner layout element instead (I dont need Spinner functionality, only it has to look like real Spinner). But ImageView and TextView has same problem with clicking. Still my parent onClickListener is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

Make on Click Listener for All of the views and then call your function, so it does not matter on which view you click. It will always trigger that function.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout;
TextView textView;
Spinner spinner;

linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.clickableLayout);
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.picker);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.text1);

    linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myFunction();
        }
    });

    spinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myFunction();
        }
    });
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myFunction();
        }
    });
}

private void myFunction() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I think you should not be calling myFunction() method for spinner and textview.

Comment: disable spinner, so no click will be detected

Comment: spinner is disabled but it is still clickable or focusable becasue onClickListener for parent is not fired if I click over Spinner view

Comment: but spinner onclick will be fired, which will also call the same fuction

Comment: You cannot register onClickListener for spinner, because its AdapterView it will crash your app. Only onItemSelected listener

Comment: Thats beign said even if I disabled ontouch listeners , arrow which will show drop-down menu and it's part of spinner is still clickable/focusable